# Possibility of importing and using an external library in ROS nodes

Tags: kinect, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I wonder whether it is possible to import & use other external libraries in my ROS's node. In my case, I need to know if I can use [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html?highlight=kinect) OpenCV library in my kinect node or not. If it is,

What changes do I apply to installation path of this library or Cmakelist file of my ros package or else?.

What is the difference between this library and that of available in ROS?

Thanks for helping me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201073/possibility-of-importing-and-using-an-external-library-in-ros-nodes/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is definitely possible (and very common) to use external libraries in ROS nodes. Depending on the language and library you want to use, the required steps will change somewhat, but in general ROS tries to follow the typical usage patterns of the language (e.g., CMake for C++, etc.).

However, for libraries that extremely popular to use with ROS, such as OpenCV, pre-baked distributions are already built for several platforms. This is done so that you don't have to build (and continually update) it yourself, and to guarantee a consistent library version for other packages in the ROS build farm that also require OpenCV.

For example, if you're using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu, you can just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-vision-opencv
```

And then you can follow the [documentation and tutorials on the ROS vision_opencv page](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) for examples on how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-15**:
Many Thanks for your clear answer.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-01-15**:
@Alireza_m please accept the answer from @Morgan using the checkmark button at the left of his answer so others know your problem is solved when they search.